# how to delete an image from an array in function component

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, function, components

The handleRemoveImgButn should remove the first image, but when I click the handleRemoveImgButn, the image is not removing from the DOM. I also tried setImgs((prevImgs) => prevImgs.filter(img => prevImgs.indexOf(img) !== 0, but it doesn't work. Below is the code. Thanks for any help in advance.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import AddImgButn from "./AddImgButn";
import RemoveImgButn from "./RemoveImgButn";

export default function App() {
  const [imgs, setImgs] = useState([]);

  
  const handleAddImgClick = () => {
    fetchId();
  };

  const handleRemoveImgClick = () => {
    setImgs((prevImgs) => prevImgs.splice(1));
  };

  return (
    <>
      <h1>Catt</h1>
      <div>
        <AddImgButn onClick={handleAddImgClick} />
        <RemoveImgButn onClick={handleRemoveImgClick} />
      </div>
      <div>
        {imgs.map((img, i) => (
          <img key={i} src={img} className="cat" alt="cat" />
        ))}
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: are you sure onClick event works for `<RemoveImgButn>` tag?

Comment: I was able to execute this code locally and everything works. I think button components causing problems. to debug try to replace it with: <button onClick={handleAddImgClick} >add</button> and <button onClick={handleRemoveImgClick} >remove</button>

Comment: @WilliamWang You are right, I didn't add onClick to it on another file. Thanks a lot

Comment: Bravo @WilliamWang
even though
Always be careful not to change the state and then do setState
It makes a lot of trouble

Comment: you still have an issue? i can see that you approved answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because `splice` changes the old array

Then `useEffect` does not detect a change between it and the new one

You can use `slice` instead

```
 const handleRemoveImgClick = () => {
    setImgs((prevImgs) => prevImgs.slice(1));
  };
```